# What cityscape is this picture of?

Tags: identify-this, cities

I have come across this cityscape on the [web](http://www.wallpapervortex.com/photography-cityscape-wallpapers-page2.html) and I wonder what city it is. Does anyone know?

[image: cityscape]

Comment: I realize that this is probably only worth a comment, but I am not allowed to comment yet, so bear with my answer. Have you tried here: http://www.where-is-this.com/ ?

Comment: So which price is attached to this photo? In my opinion this question is off topic, unless it is embedded in question that expressed the desire to go there.

Comment: @Andra: I asked because I would like to visit this city in the future. Should I append that in the question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Definitely Hong Kong, with Victoria Peak in the background.

Most likely taken from somewhere around [North Point](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=North%20Point,%20Hong%20Kong) - based on the angle I'd say from the top of one of the high-rise buildings in that area.

The original photo is posted on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/crystalbeta/2110417115/), although without any details of exactly where it was taken.  The same photographer has some other fairly impressive similar photos as well!

Answer (score 13):

[TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/search/ff9281a3806f32b7ee6192f15b89a24cb79a4c88/) says it's [Hong Kong](http://img.uuhy.com/uploads/2010/10/hong-kong-rush-wallpapers_6825_1600x1200.jpg), and based on the scenery that does seem likely.

Comment: do they drive on the right or the left in Hong Kong? The picture shows driving on the left.

Comment: @Kate: [On the left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_side#Hong_Kong).

Comment: @jpatokal: seems the TinEye query link leads to an expired search. Could you please add some kind of instruction to the link for others to reproduce the search?

Comment: @Jonas Copy the URL of the photo into Tineye. You can also use Google reverse image search.

Answer (score 9):

Given the name of this image, I'd say it's Hong Kong:

[`http://img.uuhy.com/uploads/2010/10/hong-kong-rush-wallpapers_6825_1600x1200.jpg`](http://img.uuhy.com/uploads/2010/10/hong-kong-rush-wallpapers_6825_1600x1200.jpg)

**EDIT**

I checked with my Kiwi friend who lives in Hong Kong; he believes it's overlooking [Causeway Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causeway_Bay).